# code gives segmentation fault(code dumped)

Tags: c

I dont know why this code gives segementation fault(code dumped) is there something wrong with the syntax

```
#include <stdio.h>

int checksub(char strng){
  int a=strlen(strng);
  printf("%d",a);
}
int main(){
  checksub("twoi");
}
```

Comment: `strlen()` on a singular `char` is a good way to get a segmentation fault. This *only* works on a `char*` that points to a C string that **is `NUL` terminated**.

Comment: `strng` is not a pointer to `char`, you are passing the wrong data type to `strlen` -> undefined behaviour. Read the compiler warnings, they are there for a reason.

Comment: Why did you change the code in the question? Does it give you segfault too? I doubt it.

Comment: No, it does not work like this. The question is supposed to remain a question. There are answers to point out the mistake. Rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a `char*` argument, so you must accept one. Further, you're promising to return `int` but fail to do so. Third, you've got a single-use variable that's basically irrelevant, so you can simplify to this:

```c
void checksub(char* strng) {
  printf("%d", strlen(strng));
}
```

Where `strlen()` returns `size_t`, you'll actually need:

```c
void checksub(char* strng) {
  printf("%zu", strlen(strng));
}
```

--

There's a lot of things your compiler should have warned you about here, so turn on `-Wall` or equivalent and **pay close attention**.

Comment: You have \UB!!!!!!

Comment: @0___________ Do you want to clarify?

Comment: @tadman, `strlen` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`

Comment: @HAL9000 A good point, so added a fix. I use `clang` which normally complains, vigorously, about mistakes like this, which is nice because you can care less about these details up-front.